# Adding a .CSV file to excel as a sheet in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I'm able to add a dataframe to excel as a separate sheet. However, I want to be able to add a .CSV file that is already created as a sheet.

Code that works to add dataframe as a sheet:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(dataframe, file = excelFileName,
           sheetName=excelsheetname, append=TRUE,row.names = FALSE)
```

I need to be able to replicate the same thing as above. However, instead of a dataframe, it is a .CSV file. Is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: The .csv file cannot be read to a dataframe. It containts multiple dataframe with each one having its own set of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works and suits my needs.

```
csvDF = read.csv(file = csvFileName, as.is = 1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE)
write.xlsx(csvDF , file = excelFileName,sheetName=sheetNameInfo, append=TRUE,row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, here is a template that you can use to import an Excel file into R:

```
library("readxl")
read_excel("Path where your Excel file is stored\\File Name.xlsx")
```

And if you want to import a specific sheet within the Excel file, then you may use this template:

```
library("readxl")
read_excel("Path where your Excel file is stored\\File Name.xlsx",sheet = "Your sheet name")
```

Note: In the R Console, type the following command to install the readxl package:

```
install.packages("readxl")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only step missing in your solution is to first read the CSV file into a dataframe using `read.csv` or `read.table`:

```
library(xlsx)
dataframe <- read.csv(csv)
write.xlsx(dataframe, file = excelFileName,
           sheetName=excelsheetname, append=TRUE,row.names = FALSE)
```

If you specifically want to add a csv to an excel sheet **without first reading it in** then that is another story, and you should clarify it in your question.

Comment: The only challenge is that the .CSV file have many dataframe in it and the column format is not consistent. (Not all dataframes have same column formats).

Comment: your question could be made clearer: it seems worthwhile to mention that your CSV file cannot be read into a dataframe. Perhaps you can post an example of some lines of your csv